# How to setup Jitsi Meet on a custom Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, jitsi, jitsi-meet, prosody-im

We have a single node kubernetes environment hosted on an on prem server and we are attempting to host jitsi on it as a single pod. Jitsi web, jicofo, jvb and the prosody will be in on one pod rather than having separate pods for each ([reference here](https://github.com/DushmanthaBandaranayake/jitsi-kubernetes-scalable-service))

So far what we have managed to set it up by adding our ingress hostname to as the PUBLIC_URL to all 4 containers within the pod. This service works fine if two users are on the same network.

If a user using another network joins the call, there is no video or audio and will receive such an error in the jvb container

> JVB 2022-03-16 02:03:28.447 WARNING: [62] [confId=200d989e4b048ad3 gid=116159 stats_id=Durward-H4W conf_name=externalcropsjustifynonetheless@muc.meet.jitsi ufrag=4vfdk1fu8vfgn1 epId=eaff1488 local_ufrag=4vfdk1fu8vfgn1] ConnectivityCheckClient.startCheckForPair#374: Failed to send BINDING-REQUEST(0x1)[attrib.count=6 len=92 tranID=0xBFC4F7917F010AF9DA6E21D7]
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No socket found for 172.17.0.40:10000/udp->192.168.1.23:42292/udp
> at org.ice4j.stack.NetAccessManager.sendMessage(NetAccessManager.java:631)
> at org.ice4j.stack.NetAccessManager.sendMessage(NetAccessManager.java:581)
> at org.ice4j.stack.StunClientTransaction.sendRequest0(StunClientTransaction.java:267)
> at org.ice4j.stack.StunClientTransaction.sendRequest(StunClientTransaction.java:245)
> at org.ice4j.stack.StunStack.sendRequest(StunStack.java:680)
> at org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient.startCheckForPair(ConnectivityCheckClient.java:335)
> at org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient.startCheckForPair(ConnectivityCheckClient.java:231)
> at org.ice4j.ice.ConnectivityCheckClient$PaceMaker.run(ConnectivityCheckClient.java:938)
> at org.ice4j.util.PeriodicRunnable.executeRun(PeriodicRunnable.java:206)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
> at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)

Furthermore the errors in the browser console are as such

[image]

**EDIT**

I have added the yaml file for the jitsi here

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    k8s-app: jitsi
  name: jitsi
  namespace: default
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      k8s-app: jitsi
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        k8s-app: jitsi
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: jicofo
          image: jitsi/jicofo:stable-7001
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /config
              name: jicofo-config-volume
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: XMPP_SERVER
              value: localhost
            - name: XMPP_DOMAIN
              value: meet.jitsi
            - name: XMPP_AUTH_DOMAIN
              value: auth.meet.jitsi
            - name: PUBLIC_URL
              value: <hidden>
            - name: XMPP_INTERNAL_MUC_DOMAIN
              value: internal-muc.meet.jitsi
            - name: JICOFO_COMPONENT_SECRET
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jitsi-config
                  key: JICOFO_COMPONENT_SECRET
            - name: JICOFO_AUTH_USER
              value: focus
            - name: JICOFO_AUTH_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jitsi-config
                  key: JICOFO_AUTH_PASSWORD
            - name: TZ
              value: America/Los_Angeles
            - name: JVB_BREWERY_MUC
              value: jvbbrewery
        - name: prosody
          image: jitsi/prosody:stable-7001
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /config
              name: prosody-config-volume
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: XMPP_DOMAIN
              value: meet.jitsi
            - name: XMPP_AUTH_DOMAIN
              value: auth.meet.jitsi
            - name: XMPP_MUC_DOMAIN
              value: muc.meet.jitsi
            - name: PUBLIC_URL
              value: <hidden>
            - name: XMPP_INTERNAL_MUC_DOMAIN
              value: internal-muc.meet.jitsi
            - name: JICOFO_COMPONENT_SECRET
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jitsi-config
                  key: JICOFO_COMPONENT_SECRET
            - name: JVB_AUTH_USER
              value: jvb
            - name: JVB_AUTH_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jitsi-config
                  key: JVB_AUTH_PASSWORD
            - name: JICOFO_AUTH_USER
              value: focus
            - name: JICOFO_AUTH_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jitsi-config
                  key: JICOFO_AUTH_PASSWORD
            - name: TZ
              value: America/Los_Angeles
            - name: JVB_TCP_HARVESTER_DISABLED
              value: "true"
        - name: web
          image: jitsi/web:stable-7001
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: XMPP_SERVER
              value: localhost
            - name: JICOFO_AUTH_USER
              value: focus
            - name: PUBLIC_URL
              value: <hidden>
            - name: XMPP_DOMAIN
              value: meet.jitsi
            - name: XMPP_AUTH_DOMAIN
              value: auth.meet.jitsi
            - name: XMPP_INTERNAL_MUC_DOMAIN
              value: internal-muc.meet.jitsi
            - name: XMPP_BOSH_URL_BASE
              value: http://127.0.0.1:5280
            - name: XMPP_MUC_DOMAIN
              value: muc.meet.jitsi
            - name: TZ
              value: America/Los_Angeles
            - name: JVB_TCP_HARVESTER_DISABLED
              value: "true"
        - name: jvb
          image: jitsi/jvb:stable-7001
          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /config
              name: jvb-config-volume
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: XMPP_SERVER
              value: localhost
            - name: DOCKER_HOST_ADDRESS
              value: <hidden>
            - name: XMPP_DOMAIN
              value: meet.jitsi
            - name: XMPP_AUTH_DOMAIN
              value: auth.meet.jitsi
            - name: XMPP_INTERNAL_MUC_DOMAIN
              value: internal-muc.meet.jitsi
            - name: PUBLIC_URL
              value: <hidden>
            # - name: JVB_STUN_SERVERS
            #   value: stun.l.google.com:19302,stun1.l.google.com:19302,stun2.l.google.com:19302
            - name: JICOFO_AUTH_USER
              value: focus
            - name: JVB_TCP_HARVESTER_DISABLED
              value: "true"
            - name: JVB_AUTH_USER
              value: jvb
            - name: JVB_PORT
              value: "10000"
            - name: JVB_TCP_PORT 
              value: "4443"
            - name: JVB_TCP_MAPPED_PORT 
              value: "4443"
            # - name: JVB_ENABLE_APIS
            #   value: "rest,colibri"
            - name: JVB_AUTH_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jitsi-config
                  key: JVB_AUTH_PASSWORD
            - name: JICOFO_AUTH_PASSWORD
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jitsi-config
                  key: JICOFO_AUTH_PASSWORD
            - name: JVB_BREWERY_MUC
              value: jvbbrewery
            - name: TZ
              value: America/Los_Angeles
      volumes:
        - name: jvb-config-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /home/jitsi-config/jvb
        - name: jicofo-config-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /home/jitsi-config/jicofo
        - name: prosody-config-volume
          hostPath:
            path: /home/jitsi-config/prosody
```

**EDIT 2**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    service: web
  name: web
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
    - name: "http"
      protocol: TCP
      port: 80
      targetPort: 80
      nodePort: 31015
    - name: "https"
      protocol: TCP
      port: 443
      targetPort: 443
      nodePort: 30443
    - name: "prosody"
      protocol: TCP
      port: 5222
      targetPort: 5222
    - port: 30300
      name: jvb-0
      protocol: UDP
      targetPort: 30300
      nodePort: 30300
    # - name: "jvbport"
    #   protocol: TCP
    #   port: 9090
    #   targetPort: 9090
    - name: "udp"
      protocol: UDP
      port: 10000
      targetPort: 10000
    # - name: "udp-secondary"
    #   protocol: UDP
    #   port: 20000
    #   targetPort: 20000
    - name: "test"
      protocol: TCP
      port: 4443
      targetPort: 4443
  selector:
    k8s-app: jitsi
  type: NodePort
---
# service for jvbs
# create service for jvb upd access on kubernetes Nodeport starting with 31000.
# Make sure NodePorts between 31000-31005 are available on your kube cluster.
# update this if you need JVBs more than 6.
# JVB-0
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  labels:
    service: jvb-0
  name: jvb-0
  namespace: default
spec:
  type: NodePort
  externalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ports:
    - port: 31000
      name: jvb-0
      protocol: UDP
      targetPort: 31000
      nodePort: 31000
    # - name: "udp"
    #   protocol: UDP
    #   port: 10000
    #   targetPort: 10000
    # - name: "jvbport"
    #   protocol: TCP
    #   port: 9090
    #   targetPort: 9090
  selector:
    app: jvb
    "statefulset.kubernetes.io/pod-name": jvb-0
---
```

Comment: What is your Kubernetes version? Does this server has a public IP? Do you use external DNS? Which [Ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/#additional-controllers) do you use? Could you share your yaml configuration?

Comment: @RadekW versionj is 1.22.2 and yes the server does have a public ip and that public ip is used on an external DNS. I have used an nginx ingress controller.

Comment: Could you try deploy [simple app](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/)? If it will work, the problem will be with Jitsi meet.

Comment: @lp_nave issue is related to jvb, can you post the service spec?

Comment: @Diego I have added the service spec as requested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to fix it. Posting this for anyone who comes across the same issue.

first off the UDP port 10000 does not work in kubernetes as you can only expose ports between 30000 to 32768. Having said that you need to pick a port within that range and use it for the JVB_PORT configuration in the JVB container.

secondly use that port in the service lay to expose it to the front end

```
- name: "udp"
  protocol: UDP
  port: 31000
  targetPort: 31000
  nodePort: 31000
```

Thirdly, regarding the firewall and, if you are behind a company firewall, make sure you have enabled ingress and egress for your JVB_PORT